# How to append a string near a particular string in a file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sed

I want to append a string after a particular string in a file but not into new line.

For example, I want to add `two` after `=`.

Before executing file:

```
one
two=
three
four
five
```

After executing file:

```
one
two=two
three
four
five
```

How can I do this with a sed command?

Comment: You can use: `sed 's/=/&two/' file`

Comment: Thank you @anubhava this is what I want.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you would like to do that in place:

```
sed -i 's/=/=two/' /path/to/file
```

That does a **search & replace**; the found equal gets replaced with =two.

Should you want to keep a backup of the original just add an extension right after the -i, e.g.

```
sed -i.bak 's/=/=two/' /path/to/file
```